# How to post a reply to a Twitter user using STTwitter

Tags: ios, twitter, sttwitter

I'm having trouble in posting a reply to a specific status ID

Here's my authentication code

```
twitterWithReply = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];

[twitterWithReply verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

       NSLog(@"Login Successful");
       self.replyTextField.enabled = YES;

}


errorBlock:^(NSError *error){

       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                  message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];
    }];
```

And here's my code for posting the reply

```
NSLog(@"the text content%@",self.replyTextField.text);
    [self.replyTextField resignFirstResponder];
    if (self.replyTextField.text.length>0 && self.replyTextField.text.length <=140) {
        // Post reply
        [twitterWithReply postStatusUpdate:self.replyTextField.text inReplyToStatusID:self.tweeetID latitude:nil longitude:nil placeID:nil displayCoordinates:nil trimUser:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {
            [self showSuccessDialog];
        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }];

    }
```

Currently what it does is to post to my own timeline not in reply to a specific tweet. I'm under the impression that my authentication code is wrong. So how do I authenticate then?

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Also, try to log the tweetID and ensure it's correct.

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It just posts into my own timeline not in reply to a specific tweet. I checked the tweetID and I think it's correct, I used the id_str parameter from the statuses got from 
 [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:twitterName successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses)

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this scenario with the development version of STTwitter and it works as expected.

If this code doesn't work for you, then please [fill an issue](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/issues) with as much details as possible.

```
self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];

[_twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

    [_twitter postStatusUpdate:@"test1" inReplyToStatusID:nil latitude:nil longitude:nil placeID:nil displayCoordinates:nil trimUser:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {

        NSLog(@"-- status1: %@", status);

        [_twitter postStatusUpdate:@"test2" inReplyToStatusID:[status valueForKey:@"id_str"] latitude:nil longitude:nil placeID:nil displayCoordinates:nil trimUser:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {
            NSLog(@"-- status2: %@", status);
        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"-- error2: %@", error);
        }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"-- error1: %@", error);
    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"-- error0: %@", error);
}];
```

[image]

Comment: i am using STTwitterAPI in iOS to give reply to the tweet from other account, i can reply to the tweet from same account from i am unable to give reply from other account. can you please help me out how to do this.